# Why there is no paper optimize the consumption power of the circuit in energy harvest?

Tags: digital-communications

In the optimization of  energy harvest ,some paper want to maximize the harvested power ,rate or minimize the transmitted power,so when they write the formula of optimization,they may assume the beamforming,transmitted power  power splitter ,power allocation as variable.

However,i am confused that why there is no one assume the "consumption of circuit" as variable ? All of paper are either assume it is a constant value or just ignore them.

Does anyone know or have a good explanation about we don't assume  "consumption of circuit" as variable?

In my opinion,i think the purpose of optimizing something in the energy harvesting is that we want to let the life of battery become longer when we "transmit" the signal correctly,so we will focus on something which has a relation with the transmitted power,like SNR  or power splitter,beamforming direction,etc.

Does anyone know or have a better explanation about it?Because we do need a circuit to transmit the signal,and the signal does consumpt the power

Comment: i worked on a project about 10 years ago where it would have helped a lot to know those power consumption numbers. I was told that they were closely held proprietary numbers and you really needed to be in the business interest of the chip manufacturers to even get an NDA. Don’t know if this is still true. What I did find out is that the power consumption varies according to the kind of processing.

Comment: yes,but if we assume the power consumption of circuit as variable,we can know what value of  the power consumption has to be,or is it unreasonable to know this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone wants to minimize the power of their circuits, so there's nothing special about energy harvesting devices, at all.

Also, every paper about making communications more reliable while is about making the power usage lower, simply because if you want constant reliability, you can then achieve that with lower power.

Basically, all the research on transmitters  uses the energy per bit as the critical measure, so you really don't need to look for energy harvesting-specific papers.

So, this really boils down to basic textbook knowledge of transmitter design, not to speciality papers.

Now, that's on the theoretical side of things. When it comes to building silicon doing the things that you derived are good in theory, then you'll find that modern silicon's manufacturing techniques are very much limited by the power consumption of devices – so, the secrets that you're asking for a worth billions of Qualcomm's, Apple's, ZTE's, and (formerly) intel's money.

Comment: so what do you think about that we will assume the transmitted power as variable,but not the power consumption as variable in the energy harvest?

Comment: Because i can't see any reason about we won't assume the power consumption as variable in your  answer

Comment: because it's an independent optimization target we don't need to consider it here. "I can't see any reason about we won't assume…", sorry, I don't see any reason why we should. Occam's razor is on my side unless you can definitely link your power harvesting system's performance to this particular problem